# Conditional parameters in SSRS

Tags: sql, sql-server, reporting-services, parameters

Is there a more efficient way to create SQL query for an SSRS report where, depending on the parameter value, it would return records filtered against a date field:  1 = all rows without end date 2 = all rows with end date 3 = all rows regardless of parameter value.  I have come up with below query but using boolean it requires an or statement to be duplicate for every condition (I have to add a lot more conditions!

The other issue/problem I've had is when using IF or CASE - I get an error message saying sclar variable not valid.  When I declare and set the parameter with default value it works.  But not sure if CASE/IF are ideal in this case?  Thank you.

```
SELECT table.field_seq_no, table.field_end_dt, MyTable2.area_off
FROM table 
INNER JOIN MyTable2 
  ON table.comp_id = MyTable2.comp_id 
  AND table.prty_ref = MyTable2.prty_id
WHERE ((table.field_end_dt IS NULL)
  AND (@Parameter = 1) 
  AND (MyTable2.area_off IN (@area)) 
OR ((table.field_end_dt IS NOT NULL) 
  AND (@Parameter = 2) 
  AND (MyTable2.area_off IN (@area)) 
OR ((@Parameter = 3) AND (MyTable2.area_off IN (@area))
```

Comment: It's usually a bad idea to use case expressions in the where clause. (Difficult to optimize, etc.)

Comment: Personally, I would move this the the expression in SSRS and use `switch(Parameters!Parameter1.Value = 1, <SQL1>, Parameters!Parameter1.Value = 2, <SQL2>, Parameters!Parameter1.Value = 3, <SQL3>)`

Answer (score 0):

If you change your query just a little there is actually no repeated code, ignoring the check for the `@Parameter` value:

```
select t1.field_seq_no
      ,t1.field_end_dt
      ,t2.area_off

from table t1
  inner join MyTable2 t2
    on t1.comp_id = t2.comp_id 
      and t1.prty_ref = t2.prty_id
      and t2.area_off IN (@area)    -- This part is consistent so doesn't need to be repeated.

where (@Parameter = 1
       and t1.field_end_dt is null
      )
  or (@Parameter = 2
      and t1.field_end_dt is not null
     )
  or @Parameter = 3;
```

Of course, if you feel that filtering statements should not be in the `JOIN` clauses, you can put it in your `WHERE` with some extra parenthesis:

```
select t1.field_seq_no
      ,t1.field_end_dt
      ,t2.area_off

from table t1
  inner join MyTable2 t2
    on t1.comp_id = t2.comp_id 
      and t1.prty_ref = t2.prty_id

where t2.area_off IN (@area)    -- This part is consistent so doesn't need to be repeated.
  and (
         (@Parameter = 1
           and t1.field_end_dt is null
         )
      or (@Parameter = 2
          and t1.field_end_dt is not null
         )
      or @Parameter = 3
      );
```